# How to combine php, html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have three files a .php, a .html and a .js. How can I combine all three of them so that I can use the value of a variable set in php in JavaScript?

Comment: Learn about AJAX.

Comment: Depends on how they are linked together

Comment: Show your code. The HTML can probably go in the PHP page. The PHP variable could be echo'd to the JS as a variable `var php_var = '<?php echo $var; ?>';`. PHP is not available once the page has loaded, if the PHP var needs to be dynamic you'll need ajax.

Comment: I'm so wondering why this question received an upvote just now which provided no code and showed no effort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: ^ that, being the duplicate I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to save this file by .php extenstion

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
 <?php
   // here I can write my php code ?> // I can end it any time to include some JS code here 
<script> Some js code</script>
<?php // and start again to write some more php code 
?>
</body>
</html>
```